# Reset a field based on selection of another in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a drop down field in VBA called **cbo_deptCode**. I would like another set of fields called **cbo_moduleCode** and **cbo_moduleName** to be cleared of any current entry each time the user makes a selection from the drop down **cbo_deptCode**. The combo boxes are form controls. How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: Are the combo boxes ActiveX or Form controls?  Or created by Data Validation?

Comment: The combo boxes are form controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a macro to cbo_deptCode.

In the macro have code like the following:

```
Sub cbo_deptCode_Change()
    'Update selected index for combo boxes to 0 I.E. no selection
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("cbo_moduleCode").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("cbo_moduleName").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 0
End Sub
```

If cbo_moduleCode and cbo_moduleName are not on the same sheet as cbo_deptCode, you'll need to specify the sheet instead of calling the ActiveSheet. Also, this will fail if those aren't the actual control names.

**EDIT:**
If you are actually using Active-X controls (though you said you were using form controls), the format is simpler:
`Sheet.[controlname].value = ""` I.E `ActiveSheet.cbo_moduleCode.Value = ""`
Or the more convoluted method (not recommended) that involves Shapes:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes("cbo_moduleCode").OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = ""`

Comment: I get **"Compile error - ambigious name detected - cbo_deptCode - change"**. Is it because of this other code I have :http://pastebin.com/q1m5f2Yh?

Comment: Yes. Just change the name on either Sub. You should not have two subs with the same name. If you want the other sub to be the one called, just copy what I gave you into your already existing code sans the Sub declaration and End Sub.

Comment: I've just realised that I need to change the ActiveSheet part of the code. I've tried using this code but it doesn't work: http://pastebin.com/Kh2ac0S0

Comment: Are you sure you have the names right? When you click on the shape, the name should appear in the name box (left of the formula bar, which must be displayed.). I'm updating my answer just incase you're using Active-X Controls.