# VBA Run-time error -214724809 (80070057)

Tags: excel, vba

I want fill a drop down list based on user selection in another. I'm trying to update the contents of a field based on selection in another by adding the items on the fly once the first combobox (cbo_park) is selected.

I have a four drop down lists:

The first drop down **cbo_park** has the following options:

```
Central
East
West
```

I have a second workbook called **lookupRoom** which contains the following table:

```
roomCode    park
A.0.01      Central 
A.2.01      Central 
A.3.01      Central 
HE.0.10     East
HE.0.21     East
HE.0.22     East
KG.1.07     West
KG.1.09     West
KG.1.10     West
```

When the user selects the Central park option under the first drop down **cbo_park** I only want rooms in the Central park to be displayed in dropdown **cbo_prefRoom1**, **cbo_prefRoom2** and **cbo_prefRoom3**. How would I go about achieving this?

Please find below my attempts so far. I keep receiving an error at the line: `Me.cbo_prefRoom1.RemoveItem 0`.

```
Private Sub cbo_park_Change()

Dim lLoop As Long, rgLoop As Range

    For lLoop = 1 To Me.cbo_park.ListCount

        Me.cbo_prefRoom1.RemoveItem 0

    Next lLoop

    Sheets("lookupRoom").[a1].CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    Sheets("lookupRoom").[a1].CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Left(Me.cbo_park.Value, 2)

    For Each rgLoop In Sheets("lookupRoom").[a1].CurrentRegion.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Columns(1).Cells
        If Len(rgLoop) > 0 Then
            Me.cbo_prefRoom1.AddItem rgLoop
        End If
    Next rgLoop

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably becdause you are looping over the length of `cbo_park`, but deleting from `cbo_prefRoom1`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How can I resolve this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my solution for achieving this.

I rewrote everything to be contained in just the one `For` loop and set it to update both comboboxes.

```
Private Sub cbo_park_Change()

    Dim lLoop As Long
    '- clear the two comboboxes we are about to update
    Me.cbo_prefRoom1.Clear
    Me.cbo_prefRoom3.Clear

    '- loop through the worksheet and test each row
    For lLoop = 1 To Sheets("lookupRoom").Range("A" & Sheets("lookupRoom").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        '- if the row's column C matches the combobox then add the corresponding values to other combos
        If Sheets("lookupRoo"m).Range("C" & lLoop).Value = Me.cbo_park.Value Then
            Me.cbo_prefRoom1.AddItem Sheets("lookupRoom").Range("B" & lLoop).Value
            Me.cbo_prefRoom2.AddItem Sheets("lookupRoom").Range("B" & lLoop).Value
        End If
    Next lLoop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve.  If it's to clear all entries from a combo box, use this

```
Do While Me.combo.ListCount > 0
    Me.combo.RemoveItem(0)
Loop
```

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this but within another context: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935491/reset-a-field-based-on-selection-of-another-in-vba

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement it without VBA and without using the combo box. Excel cells has Data  Validation which would act like a combo box. Since it part of the spreadsheet you don't have to worry about sizing and positioning.

With the label "Park" in `A2`, use `B2` as your input cell. With B2 as your active cell, go to Data -> Validation; choose `List` for Allow and just type `Central,East,West` in the Source. Try it out and see if you like your new drop down.

Now for the Rooms "trickery".

1. Type `="LookupRoom!A"&MATCH(B2,lookupRoom!B1:B10,0)&":A"&MATCH(B2,lookupRoom!B1:B10,1)` into `C2`.
2. Go to `B3` and us data validation again, but this time type `=INDIRECT($C$2)` into the source input.

Try it. Now you have a drop down that responds to your park selection.