# Run-time error when trying to select a chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a simple piece of VBA that selects each of 4 charts in turn and then runs a sub routine on them before moving onto the next.

It has been working fine for a year, but all of a sudden this month I am getting
`Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'`

```vb
Sub All_Charts()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    Absolute_Labels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    PerCent_Labels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    Absolute_Labels
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    PerCent_Labels
    
End Sub
```

The 2 different subs, `Absolute_Labels` and `PerCent_Labels`, work fine if I manually select each chart. It just won't select the charts to start.

I've tried using Record Macro and then selecting the charts and that gives me the same `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate`

Comment: `Absolute_Labels` and `PerCent_Labels` should probably be passed a `ChartObject` as a parameter.

Comment: Share the code for `Absolute_Labels` and `PerCent_Labels`

Comment: ALso is the worksheet protected?

Comment: As BigBen notes this approach is prone to failure, since it relies on something being active/selected when a piece of code runs.  Modify like `Sub Absolute_Labels(cht As Chart)` then call with `Absolute_Labels ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart`  Inside `Absolute_Labels` work with the provided `cht` Chart object.

Comment: Hi Boz, there's already an issue describing your problem. Please try searching before raising a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981033/vba-run-time-error-214724809-80070057 . If the referred article answers your question, perhaps consider delating this issue

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated in the comments above, you really should never rely on some object being `Active/Selected`. This is extremely prone to errors, and is generally bad practice.

To solve for this issue, you should pass the Chart as a parameter to your functions that way your function has direct access to the specific chart, and is not relying on a global state.

Just make sure that you also add some error handling, just in case a chart is removed down the line or renamed.

```vb
Sub All_Charts()
On Error GoTo Catch
    With ActiveSheet
        Absolute_Labels .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
        PerCent_Labels .ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
        Absolute_Labels .ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart
        PerCent_Labels .ChartObjects("Chart 4").Chart
    End With
Exit Sub
Catch:
    ' Handle any errors in case Chart is not found
    ' What do you want to do if one fails?
End Sub

Private Sub Absolute_Labels(ByRef cht As Chart)
    ' Do something with the chart
End Sub

Private Sub PerCent_Labels(ByRef cht As Chart)
    ' Do something with the chart
End Sub
```

---

To help you figure out how to reference your charts, here is a loop I made that will print to your immediate window examples of how you should be calling each individual `ChartObject`.

```vb
' Loops through every worksheet, then every chartObject
' in `ThisWorkbook`.
Private Sub listChartsInThisWorkook()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim cht As ChartObject
        For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
            With cht
                ' This will write the specific code that can be used to call each chart
                ' individually. Just for demo to see how you should be calling your charts.
                ' @example: Sheet1.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
                Debug.Print ws.CodeName & ".ChartObjects(""" & .Name & """).Chart"
            End With
        Next cht
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Robert for trying to help, but i've tried the code and it goes straight to Catch.
I 've also reduced my code to

Sub One_Charts()

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    
End Sub

To avoid any problems with other subs, and this single line still goes into Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

Comment: What worksheet is your chart on? Really, for the most part you shouldn't use `Activesheet` as this can be changed. Also, is the worksheet they are on protected by chance?

Comment: Thanks again Robert. Worksheet is called "Quarters", and no it's not protected. I have actually fixed the problem by simply making a copy of the worksheet, deleting the original, and then renaming the copy so it's got the original name, and all of a sudden it works. Don't know why but it does. But I will use what you've said to try and avoid Activesheet in future.